# add column with value depending on other column value in entity framework migration

Tags: entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first

This is my ef migration code ,

```
   protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "ColumnNew",
            table: "MyTableName",
            nullable: true);
    }
```

So , my new column name is `ColumnNew` . I already have `ColumnOne` and `ColumnTwo`.

My question is, if `ColumnOne`'s value is equal to 1 , I want to copy `ColumnTwo`'s  value to `ColumnNew` .
Can I do this in migration file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add an update statement after creating the new column:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
        name: "ColumnNew",
        table: "MyTableName",
        nullable: true);

    migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE MyTableName SET ColumnNew = ColumnTwo WHERE ColumnOne = 1");
}
```